# Can't receive a POST request from another server (Flask/Python)

Tags: python, flask, request, http-post, pythonanywhere

I'm making a website using Python/Flask. It is hosted on PythonAnywhere.

I have a members system and they have to pay for some products for that, I'm using a payment gateway from my country (Brazil). The problem is:

When the payment is done, the gateway sends me a POST request, using a url path that I informed, with the payment info and I need to get that information but it never triggers the url route that I have.

Also, I need to send back to the gateway, a GET request, with status 200 or 201, so that it knows that I received the payment info.

I can't know when the gateway will send it to me. Also, I can't redirect the user when I got the POST request.

Here the access log, from PythonAnywhere when the gateway sends me the info

> 54.88.218.97 - - [26/Jun/2020:13:40:48 +0000] "POST /test.html?data.id=27324748&type=payment HTTP/1.1" 401 22 "-"
> "MercadoPago WebHook v1.0 payment" "54.88.218.97" response-time=0.002

The URL that I informed for the gateway:

http://gamebet.pythonanywhere.com/test.html

The route for that URL:

```
@app.route('/test.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('hey')
        return_data = request.args.to_dict()
        print(return_data)
        status_code = Response(status=200)
        return status_code
```

This route never triggers, even if I remove the if condition.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: The access log indicates that the request returned a 401 HTTP error. That route requires authentication, which the caller did not provide.

Comment: Man, how dumb I am!!! I used Password protection. Of course, I would never receive it!! Thank you! It is working now!